# pip3 install not working invald syntax? (windows)

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, twint

I've tried using the pip3 install function multiple times on Python 3.9 but it never worked. I first tried it with JupyterNotebook and ended up using Anaconda to install Jupyter. I am currently trying to install Twint and InstagramOSINT but every time I use pip3 install I get an error message saying SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax. I checked to see if I have pip3 installed on my PC and I do.

Comment: ``pip3 install …`` is a *shell* command. It's not a Python statement. Install the packages *outside* of your Python program, or explicitly invoke ``pip3`` as a process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score -1):

you need to run powershell as admin otherwise you will get this error.